# Getting user input for a function to change colors

Tags: python, python-turtle

I want to write a function to make a circle but have the user choose the RGB values of that circle. I have tried using python's input function and turtle's text input and neither seem to work. Although, that may not be the problem. Help is much appreciated.

```
import turtle
# my turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()

red = int(turtle.textinput("Color", "Choose a value between 0-255:"))
#green = int(input("choose a second value between 0 -255."))
#blue = int(input("choose a third value between 0 -255."))

# my colorful circle function
def colors(r,g,b):
  t.color(r,g,b)
  t.fillcolor(r,g,b)
  t.begin_fill()
  t.circle(100)
  t.end_fill()

green = 0
blue = 0

# calling the function
colors(red,green,blue)
```

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue I see with your code is you're using RGB values of 0 - 255 whereas the turtle.py that comes with Python uses RGB values of 0.0 - 1.0 unless you specify otherwise using `colormode()`:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def colors(r, g, b):
    turtle.color(r, g, b)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(100)
    turtle.end_fill()

screen = Screen()
screen.colormode(255)

red = int(screen.numinput("Red", "Choose a value between 0-255", minval=0, maxval=255))
green = int(screen.numinput("Green", "Choose a second value between 0-255", minval=0, maxval=255))
blue = int(screen.numinput("Blue", "Choose a third value between 0-255", minval=0, maxval=255))

turtle = Turtle()

colors(red, green, blue)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Since you want numeric input, I switched from `textinput()` to `numinput()`.  However, I kept the `int()` conversion as `numinput()` returns `float` and the color functions want `int`.

Some non-standard implementations of turtle for Python assume RGB values of 0 - 255, but based on your use of `textinput()`, I assume you're using the standard Python 3 turtle.  If not, state in your question what (web site) Python you're using.